# Principal with new ASP.NET Web API

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

Some time ago I built API using asp.net Web-api beta. I read somewhere that when hosted in IIS, the web-api inherits the Identity from web application in which its running. My api is also running within a website. With beta binaries, when i logged into the site and then moved to `http://localhost:4343/webui/api/values` it will return me the correct values for the logged in user. Here is the `Get` method of values controller.

```
public IQueryable<string> Get()
        {
            var pr = Request.GetUserPrincipal();
            var username = Request.GetUserPrincipal().Identity.Name; //Null reference exception after installing vs 2012 here. Identity is null even though I am logged in 
            var values = GetUserValues(username);
            return values.AsQueryable();
        }
```

It used to work fine with beta build of web-api but with final release of vs2012 it throws null reference exception. I have converted the site to use .net 4.5 instead. Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpRequestMessage` doesn't have any method or extension such as `GetUserPrincipal`. I am not sure if beta had that or not. As I understood from your question, your app is still running on beta which is a complete disaster IMO.

As you installed VS 2012, Web API assemblies has been GACed on your machine. so, it is highly likely that you have a conflict there.

On the other hand, you can get to the identity through the following command:

```
var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
```

Comment: To my surprise VS 2012 adds `System.Net.Http.Formatting` and some other assemblies from nuget. I also thought they would be GACed but probably they are not. And `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is the route I have taken but I think accessing `User` property is cleaner approach.

Answer (score 5):

The ApiController now has a property called "User" which is the IPrincipal.

```
var pr = User.Identity.Name;
```

Internally, the User property calls Thread.CurrentPrincipal as mentioned by tugberk.

Comment: How would I set the User property after checking authentication in a `DelegatingHandler`.

Comment: In beta I used to write like `Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.UserPrincipal] = new Generic Pricipal(..);`. It seems that principal is removed from Http properties, no?

Comment: Just curious, why you are trying to set the User property? Is it for a unit test?

Comment: Not really, I need to set the `Principal` object after authenticating the user.